# read large file using python?

Tags: python

I want to read a .txt file which containing more than 25000 lines for that proposes I have written a python program, but it provided (output)only 490 lines can any one modify my program?

```
f = open('file2.txt','r')    
for line in f:    
 data=list(map(float,line.strip().split()))    
 y=[]    
 y.append(data[2])    
 print(y)
```

Comment: You're resetting `y` for each line read. That's probably not what you want.

Comment: my file containing 3 columns which representing x, y z coordinates respectively. and 27000 rows. i want to extract the second  column that is y coordinates. thats why i used y in my program

Comment: Yes, but after you read the first line, you assign an empty list to `y`. After you read the second line, you do the same thing: whatever `y` *was* referring to gets thrown away. Put `y = []` *before* the loop.

Comment: There's also little point in parsing all three values if you only want the second. Your whole loop could be replaced by `ys = [float(line.strip().split()[1]) for line in f]`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want the 3rd float per line into the `y` list, you're looking for something like

```
y = []
with open("file2.txt") as f:
    for line in f:
        data = [float(x) for x in line.strip().split()]
        y.append(data[2])
print(y)
```